# placing an image in activity background (with another image)

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I'm working on this app, which basically displays an image and some text.
background looks like this
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Auto_Racing_Black_White.svg

Now,I have literally set the background of my activity as this image.
And I want to implement a function where I can click a button and some stored image would be imported and placed and fit in the WHITE space, and also display some text in the BLACK space.

Any ideas how I would do that ?

```
package self.name.firstandroidprogram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Class2 extends Activity {

    LinearLayout layout1;
    TextView text1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        text1 = new TextView(this);

        text1.setText("RedNet");

        layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rn);


        layout1.addView(text1);

        setContentView(layout1);
    }

}
```

And here is my xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="self.name.firstandroidprogram.Class2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the text to side lob-sided? Will the other image completely cover the white space?
You should be able to achieve what you want by simply putting overlapping and imageview and a textview on top of the auto_racing_black_white imageview.

Comment: yeah images fills the white space, text on black side.

Comment: I tried putting it but it completely overlaps the image under it

Comment: Why don't you share some code, especially your xml. and even the other image

Comment: I posted my java and xml, i set the background to the image, now how do i add the other image?

Comment: I see that this is your first program. It'd probably be much easier set the layout through the xml file (and the gui if you're using eclipse or android studio). Right now you're just setting the layout of this activity to be the linear layout you create and the textview in it, without any parameters specifying location or margins. Assuming you're trying to learn, instead of just looking for someone to just supply you the code, my advice is that you should read more about android layouts, and definitely use the xml file (or the gui) to build your layout, since it's pretty static.

Comment: I.e., this is a link to the android developer page about layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Try making a relative layout as the main element of the activities layout and then placing the elements on there to semi-overlap each other to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank, i am actually trying to learn. I will take a look at all of that.

Comment: I also posted an answer giving you how to make the button do those things, so take a look at that too. Gl learning!

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving it to you to make the layout, but as I said, just use a RelativeLayout, and place things on top of each other. Also add the second image's ImageView and the TextView to the layout and just make them invisible by using `android:visibility="invisible"`. And the following code is for the button to make those two visible.

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
              iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
```